# Wang's C-subgroups and M-manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups

Let $K$ be a semisimple compact Lie group.

In [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=AUCN&pg7=MR&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=wang&s5=complex%20structures&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=66011) H.C. Wang defines a C-subgroup as a closed subgroup $U$ of $K$ such that the semisimple part of $U$ equals the semisimple part of the centralizer of a torus of $K$.

At the end of the paper he introduces M-manifolds to be homogeneous spaces $K/U$ where $K$ is a simple compact Lie group and $U$ is a semisimple C-subgroup.

At some point he says that in this case $U$ is the centralizer $Q$ of a torus of $K$.
Up to this point I only know that $U$ (semisimple C-subgroup) is the *semisimple* part of some centralizer $Q$. Why does it have to be all $Q$?

thanks

David

Comment: The centralizer of a torus contains a maximal torus. But any torus in $G$ (assuming $G$ is semisimple) satisfies your stated criterion, even if it isn't maximal. So I suspect you've misread something.

Comment: you mean every torus is a C-subgroup?

Comment: According to your second paragraph, $U$ is a C-subgroup if $U' = Z(S)'$ for $S$ a torus. If $S$ is a _maximal_ torus, then $Z(S) = S$ so $Z(S)' = S' = 1$. Then if $U$ is any torus, $U' = 1$ too, making it a C-subgroup.

Comment: Ok, all tori are C-subgroups but there might be others and I'm asking about the semisimple ones.

Comment: Let's take $K=SU(2)$, $S$ a maximal torus, $C_K(S) = S$, $U = 1 = S'$. So $U$ is semisimple and a C-subgroup. But any centralizer $Q$ contains a maximal torus, so $U\neq Q$.

Comment: I see your point. What if we add the assumption $U \neq 1$?

Comment: $K = SU(2)^2, S = T \times 1, C_K(S) = T \times SU(2), C_K(S)' = 1 \times SU(2) = U$.

Comment: Ok but Wang's setting is with $K$ simple.

Comment: $K = Spin(5), S = Spin(2), C_K(S) = Spin(2) \times Spin(3), C_K(S)' = 1 \times Spin(3) = U.$ This may be the point at which you should write the author.